# Charts in Record List View Community Builder

Tags: dashboard, community, charts, community-builder, napili

I'm using Napili template for my community builder and I'm trying to create charts from the record list view of an object tab.

[image]

My problem is the charts that I've created cannot be seen by other users, are these charts only visible to the creator/logged in user? is this not supposed to be visible to everybody in the community?

Comment: Which folder are your charts going into?Is it going to public folder?

Comment: Hi @MohithShrivastava I don't know where the charts that have been created from the record list view component goes to. Have you used this before?

Comment: Not used but you can check report folders

Comment: Tried searching for the name of my created charts on the reports tab, and it doesn't show in there anywhere.

Comment: It's dashboard right..

Comment: I should be able to see dashboards components/folders from the reports tab right. But tried going into the dashboards tab, didn't see my charts neither.